# WPMU: Cross site custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, multisite

I'm building a podcast network site, and one of the requirements is that all the shows on the network will share a list of guests and host bios. So in the end there will be a single page on the primary site that lists all the guests and hosts in the network and all the shows they have appeared on.

So is there a way to have a cross site CPT that contains all the data and can be used by each subsite?

I need users of subsites to be able to:

Add Bio's
Edit Bio's
Reference Bio id's in episode CTP meta.